# CALayer addSublayer increasing retain count?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

I think that when I add a view as a subview like such:

```
UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] init];
[self addSubview:view];
[view release];
```

that it's safe to release the view afterwards...is it the same for a CALayer object? If I create a CALayer using alloc/init, and do:

```
[self.layer addSublayer:layer];
```

is it safe to do a release of the layer afterwards?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. In general if object A needs object B it is object A's responsibility to retain it. So if "self.layer" needs "layer, it will bump the retainCount during addSublayer: , and release layer when it is no longer needed. While there are some exceptions to this, those exceptions tend to be very well documented.

Comment: This seems to be the case. We have our own custom layers so we're doing alloc/init rather than layer, but adjusting our releases seem to have fixed our problems. :)

Comment: Correction: the problem I saw is that if you "remove from superlayer" then the object CAN be destroyed even within the same block of code. i.e. if you then call "layer.sublayers" a second time, half the elements in the array are INVALID references that will crash your app. AFAICT this is incorrect from Apple - it should not happen until the RunLoop kicks in again. I just hit this problem. I'd be interested to see links to some of the "well documented" cases - maybe needs a docs bug ? :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Louis. And although it's not really necessary in this case, note that you can always use the `retainCount:` method to double-check these things in the future. For example:

```
NSLog(@"Retain count before: %d", [layer retainCount]);
[self.layer addSublayer:layer];
NSLog(@"Retain count after: %d", [layer retainCount]);
```

Comment: retainCount is infamous for not actually working. I'm guessing that's why you got downvoted (although it would be nice if the downvoter had commented)

Comment: `retainCount` works fine; you just have to remember that `autorelease` doesn't immediately modify the retain count. Only actual `retain` and `release` messages decrement the retain count (and the `release` message corresponding to that `autorelease` won't be sent until the current autoreleasepool is drained).

That said, using `retainCount` for anything *besides* debugging is a horrible code smell.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, you make a new CALayer object using the layer class method rather than alloc/init. Like so:-

```
CALayer *l = [CALayer layer];
l.frame = CGRectMake(...);
l.position = CGPointMake(...);
l.anchorpoint = CGPointMake(0,0);
l.contents = (id)someCGImageRef;
[self.layer addSublayer:l];
```

Secondly, this is where you can come unstuck because if you release the CALayer after adding it as a sublayer to your view's main layer, you'll get a crash. Or at least I did and I think it's because the layer class method adds the layer to the autorelease pool, so if you release it yourself you get a double-release and so it gets deallocated even thought he view's main layer is still using it.